# When i visit my heroku app URL i get an application error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

When i open my URL for my heroku app, i am greeted with an application error, i open the log, it seems to be an error in the wsgi.py but i havent touched this file so not sure what has gone wrong?

does anyone know how to deal with this or what the problem is?

the heroku log is below

```
2019-07-21T11:54:46.385562+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn pages_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2019-07-21T11:54:48.492272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-21T11:54:48.498164+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-21T11:54:48.350477+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-07-21T11:54:48.351441+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8787 (4)
2019-07-21T11:54:48.351625+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-07-21T11:54:48.357939+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:48 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371312+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:48 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371321+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371328+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371334+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371337+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371338+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371340+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371342+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371352+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371354+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371356+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371358+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371360+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371362+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371364+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371366+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371373+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/pages_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371375+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371377+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2019-07-21T11:54:48.371452+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:48 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-07-21T11:54:48.404268+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-07-21T11:54:48.404338+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-07-21T11:54:48.472114+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-07-21T11:54:51.783744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn pages_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2019-07-21T11:54:52.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-07-21T11:54:53.508785+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-21T11:54:53.488668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-07-21T11:54:53.360032+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-07-21T11:54:53.360985+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:33991 (4)
2019-07-21T11:54:53.361140+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-07-21T11:54:53.365544+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:53 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373700+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-21 11:54:53 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373709+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373714+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373722+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373723+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373725+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373726+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373728+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373732+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373734+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373735+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373737+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373738+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373740+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373742+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373743+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373745+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/pages_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373746+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2019-07-21T11:54:53.373748+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: you have in message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`. You have to install `django`

Comment: i already have django installed, i can run this project locally

Comment: But how did you install it on Heroku? Show your requirements.txt or Pipenv file.

Comment: you have installed locally but you still have to install it on server.

Comment: Thanks all, i swear i installed it in my pipenv, but just checked the pipfile.lock and it wasnt installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, i have installed django using `pip3 install django`

Comment: i already have django install which is confusing, i can run this on a local server just not on heroku

Comment: If you are using a virtual env try just to delete it and reinstall a new one and install django again